# Programming a switching AC current?

Tags: arduino-uno, pwm, arduino-motor-shield

I tried using this code to output AC power from one H-bridge and then another, switching every second, but when I connected a motor to it, it just seemed to output direct current. This is the code I was using (by the way, the motor controller I'm using has a max frequency of 20 kHz, so that's not the problem as far as I know):

```
int EnablePin = 8;
int duty;
int PWMPinA;
int PWMPinB;

const byte CPin = 0;  // analog input channel
int CRaw;      // raw A/D value
float CVal;    // adjusted Amps value

void setup() {                
  pinMode(EnablePin, OUTPUT);     
  pinMode(PWMPinA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PWMPinB, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {

  digitalWrite(EnablePin, HIGH);

  for(duty = 0; duty <= 20000; duty += 1){

    PWMPinA=11;  // Timer2
    PWMPinB=3;
    analogWrite(PWMPinA, 255);
    analogWrite(PWMPinB, 0);
    delayMicroseconds(50);

    if(PWMPinA == 11) {
      PWMPinA = 3;
      PWMPinB = 11;
    } else {
      PWMPinA = 11;
      PWMPinB = 3;
    }

  }
  for(duty = 20000; duty>=0; duty -= 1){

    PWMPinA=6;  // Timer2
    PWMPinB=5;
    analogWrite(PWMPinA, 255);
    analogWrite(PWMPinB, 0);
    delayMicroseconds(50); 

    if(PWMPinA == 6) {
      PWMPinA = 5;
      PWMPinB = 6;
    } else {
      PWMPinA = 6;
      PWMPinB = 5;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ..... Your outputing PWM signals to 4 difference pins? its very confusing to be changing the pin assigned to a variable rather then having them all defined and changing which one you are using.    Need to post a schematic of what you have done if you want any help

Comment: I tried that and it seems to work.  Don't know why I didn't think of that considering it's simpler, but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have it sorted already but the first major problem with your original code is that you use `PwmPinA` and `PwmPinB` in `setup()`, before they are assigned any values.

I'd be surprised if the compiler didn't warn about that. Never ignore compiler warnings! :-)